# Button Icon Not Clickable..but the rest of the button is

Tags: html, css, button, icons, cdn

Basically I have a button in a custom header I'm building for a Wordpress site.
The Icon inside it is from Fontawesome, CDN set up etc. Here's the code:

```
<button onclick="menu()" style="background-color:#fff; color:#232323;" class="dd-menubtn"><i class="fas fa-bars"></i></button>

function menu() {
    document.getElementById("menu-dropdown").classList.toggle("show");
}

window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (!event.target.matches('.dd-menubtn')) {

        var dropdowns = document.getElementsByClassName("dropdownmenu-content");
        var i;

        for (i = 0; i < dropdowns.length; i++) {
            var openDropdown = dropdowns[i];

            if (openDropdown.classList.contains('show')) {
                openDropdown.classList.remove('show');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In short, the wider button area (which I can't seem to get rid of due to wordpress style) is clickable and activates the drop down, but the Icon itself (burger menu thing) is not.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Please show the code where it shows the `menu()` function. If we can't see what it does, we can't help you.

Comment: or a reproduction where we can see it in action.

Comment: Perhaps you could set up an example on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) or something so that we could troubleshoot your JS.

Comment: Add more html to your code. We need `menu-dropdown` id as well here